# Numerador de documentos por ano com Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Tenho que gerar um numerador para cada documento criado, caso vire o ano o numerador zera e começa contar novamente

```
def gerar_numerador(self, memoDepart1):
  
      try:
        ultimo_numerador_memoDepart1 = MemoDepart1.objects.filter(
            ~Q(numerador=None),
            prefixo__organizacao=memoDepart1.prefixo.organizacao,
            data_criacao__year=memoDepart1.data_instauracao.year).latest(
            'numerador').numerador
      except MemoDepart1.DoesNotExist:
        numerador_memoDepart1 = None
      else:
        numerador_memoDepart1 = ultimo_numerador_memoDepart1

      try:
        ultimo_numerador_memoDepart2 = MemoDepart2.objects.filter(
            ~Q(numerador=None), data_criacao__year=memoDepart1.data_instauracao.year).latest(
            'numerador').numerador
      except MemoDepart2.DoesNotExist:
        numerador_memoDepart2 = None
      else:
        numerador_memoDepart2 = ultimo_numerador_memoDepart2

      try:
        ultimo_numerador_memoDepart3 = MemoDepart3.objects.filter(
            ~Q(numerador=None), data_criacao__year=memoDepart1.data_instauracao.year).latest(
            'numerador').numerador
      except MemoDepart3.DoesNotExist:
        numerador_memoDepart3 = None
      else:
        numerador_memoDepart3 = ultimo_numerador_memoDepart3

      if numerador_memoDepart2 is not None and numerador_memoDepart1 is None and numerador_memoDepart3 is None:
        numerador = numerador_memoDepart2 + 1
      elif numerador_memoDepart2 is not None and numerador_memoDepart1 is not None and numerador_memoDepart3 is None:
        numerador = max(numerador_memoDepart2, numerador_memoDepart1) + 1
      elif numerador_memoDepart2 is not None and numerador_memoDepart1 is not None and numerador_memoDepart3 is not None:
        numerador = max(numerador_memoDepart2, numerador_memoDepart1, numerador_memoDepart3) + 1
      elif numerador_memoDepart1 is not None and numerador_memoDepart2 is None and numerador_memoDepart3 is None:
        numerador = numerador_memoDepart1 + 1
      elif numerador_memoDepart1 is not None and numerador_memoDepart2 is None and numerador_memoDepart3 is not None:
        numerador = max(numerador_memoDepart1, numerador_memoDepart3) + 1
      elif numerador_memoDepart3 is not None and numerador_memoDepart2 is None and numerador_memoDepart1 is None:
        numerador = numerador_memoDepart3 + 1
      elif numerador_memoDepart3 is not None and numerador_memoDepart2 is not None and numerador_memoDepart1 is None:
        numerador = max(numerador_memoDepart3, numerador_memoDepart2) + 1
      else:
        numerador = 1

      memoDepart1.numerador = numerador
      memoDepart1.save()
```

O código acima é para apenas um departamento, porém ele téra que ser compartilhado por outros 2 models, independente o documento criado em alguns desses 3 models, MemoDepart1, MemoDepart2, MemoDepart3, o numerador será sequencial e usará o próximo disponível dentre eles.

Não estou conseguindo criar essa consulta no banco e fazendo testes nesse código acima percebi que está com erro e não fazendo a comparação desejada.

Answer (score 0):

Sem informações mais detalhadas é difícil tentar resolver seu problema. Você está focado no código, mas parece ser um **problema de modelagem**. Quantos documentos são gerados por ano?

**Para resolver seu problema eu usaria a seguinte abordagem:**

Criar model para o seu numerador (que será compartilhado) e gerar previamente esta sequência (ligada ao ano), uma quantidade suficiente de números para trabalhar durante o ano e/ou ter uma rotina que gera mais números mesmo que não tenha sido utilizados. Ao utilizar determinado número marcá-lo como usado (True) e relacionar ao departamento que utilizou. Quando virar o ano pode-se descartar os números não utilizados (excluir ou marcar como NULL), o próprio filtro pelo ano (novo ano) já "descarta" os números gerados anteriormente e não utilizados.

Esta seria a minha solução. Lembre-se que sistemas em geral não precisam ser complexos,e no final apenas "replicam a realidade" analógica para o mundo digital. Por exemplo, neste seu problema antigamente sem sistema o departamento teria uma folha com diversos números e a medida que fossem emitidos os documentos os números utilizados seriam riscados do papel, e é basicamente assim que o processo funciona.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Pensei mesmo em criar um model numerador compartilhado e os 3 documentos buscar dele, Porém o sistema que eu tenho hoje já está funcionando e teria muito mais complexidade fazer essa alteração do que comparar no código e adicionar o próximo disponivel.

Comment: No caso é criado cerca de 30 mil documentos/ano, sem limite de numerador, não posso fazer um lista e ir buscando qual está disponivel, o melhor é comparar o campo numerador nos 3 models, e adicionar +1 no próximo, e se mudar o ano o numerador zera, não tem limite na quantidade de numeros gerados.
A parte do numerador está funcionando, ele compara e adiciona o proximo, mas estou ramelando em alguma coisa ao comparar o ano, pois não está fazendo a comparação correta, e quando muda o ano o código está bugando, não consegui descobrir o que pode ser.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o código completo que estou usando!!!

Comment: @Elbercosta esta sua abordagem é muito mais complexa, tão complexa que está com dificuldade para implementar/corrigir. Com um modelo numerador (com numeros previamente gerados) você reduziria todo este seu código para umas 4 linhas. Para não gerar uma lista enorme de números é gerá-los sob demanda, por exemplo ao buscar um número disponível (livre), caso não existir gera o(s) próximo(s) e assim vai. E modificar a arquitetura neste caso não parece tão complexo, você teria duas funções uma gerar_numero() e outra obter_numero(). Fato é que se você persiste os números fica mais fácil manipular.